# Preprocessing conditionals in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, preprocessor, erb

I want to DRY the code as much as I can, but I think this maybe too dry..

I have a `fields_for` partial, that sometimes I need to have it by relation and sometimes `fields_for` for the object itself

```
<%= form_for model_name do |f| %>


 <%= render partial: 'fields_for_partial', locals: {f: f, ... } %>

<% end %>
```

calling the fields_for partial would be different depending on when I need the form - if I want to create a new model I would use the `form_for`'s `f`, but sometimes I want to edit the model and just show a particular nested model, which then I would use `fields_for nil, obj` to render the fields for that specific object

I attempted to do this when testing a local variable `f` that I am passing

```
<% if f.nil? %>
    <%= fields_for object_name, obj do |ff| %>
<% else %>
    <%= f.fields_for object_name, obj do |ff| %>
<% end %>
```

the rest of the partial would be a regular `fields_for` with `ff` like

which is obviously a massive fail..

How would I write this kind of code?

Comment: What is `f`? And how do you want to handle the other parts of this code block? I.E the contents of `fields_for`?

Comment: f would either be nil or the form_for block variable (that calls the fields_for partial

Comment: Surely `f` would be present if you're loading a form? I don't get what you're trying to do? A single form for all?

Comment: Form should be there, if you are writing `form_for`. If you are not sure, don't use form_for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local_assigns:

```
<% form_or_view = local_assigns[:f] || self %>
<%= form_or_view.fields_for object_name, obj do |ff| %>
```

Comment: The problem with the first solution is that it clashes with the <%else%> and <% end %>

Comment: Yep, you need to go with second option. Removed first as not-applicable.

Comment: Thanks! I had to change it to form_or_view.fields_for object_name || obj since rails doesn't like have an explicit name as nil

Answer (score 0):

move the call to `fields_for` outside of the shared partial.  Take for example a project and a task.  You allow users to create a project and a task at the same time.

```
# using HAML
# project form
= form_for @project do |f|
  = f.fields_for :tasks do |tf|
    = render 'tasks/form', f: tf
```

You also allow users to create only tasks.

```
# task form
= form_for @task do |f|
  = render 'tasks/form', f: f
```

The `tasks/_form.html.haml` partial will look like

```
# task fields
= f.text_field :title
= f.text_area :description
```

Comment: the problem is that sometimes I need to use fields_for in the context of a form and sometimes as a standalone just to render the fields of an object